# Highlight cells with past dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I dont know if this is something that a new programmer should true or not, but heres my problem. I have a table of 13 columns at at present about 400 rows. yes i nkow this is a large table and unfortunatley it will only be getting bigger.  what i am trying to achive with this table, somehow, is to have a function that checks the cell contents ( a date dd/mm/yyyy) in the 12th coloumn and if the date has past that it will will add a css to the row.

Through help from some very intelligent programmers i have a code that should work. but i cant get it to work in any way.

Can anyone help me out with this problem.

Thanks.

The code that i have is:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
function parseDate(dateString)
{
return new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
}

$('#names tr').each(function(index)
{
var row = $(this);
if (parseDate(elem.find("td:eq(1)").text()) < new Date())
row.addClass('row');
});
});

</script>
```

My table is set out like this:

```
<tr>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>data</td>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Data</td>
</tr>
```

ok and this is what i have now:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#sprog tr {
background: #00FF00;
}

#sprog tr.past {
background: #FF0000;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery 1.4.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
$('#sprog .date').each(function()
{
var row_date = Date.parse($(this).text().replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$2/$1/$3'));
var now_date = new Date().getTime();
if(row_date < now_date)
{
$(this).parent('tr').addClass('past');
}
}
);
}
);
</script>
<title>cells</title>
</head>

<body>
<table id="sprog">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>14/08/2010</td>
<td>20/10/2015</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td class="date">14/10/2010</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td class="date">04/10/2010</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10/12/2010</td>
<td class="date">12/10/2010</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12/10/2010</td>
<td class="date">01/01/1900</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some digging i found that i wasn't calling the jquery correctly and i should actually look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>trial cell highlight</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: transparent;
padding: 10px;
}
#demotable1 tr {
background: white;
}

#demotable1 tr.past {
background: #FF0000;
color: #999999;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

$(function()
{
$('#demotable1 .date').each(function()
{
var cell_date = Date.parse($(this).text().replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$2/$1/$3'));
var now_date = new Date().getTime();
if(cell_date < now_date)
{
$(this).parent('tr').addClass('past')
}
}
);
}
);

//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="demotable1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Date of Birth</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bob</td>
<td class="date">01/02/2003</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Johnny</td>
<td class="date">03/02/1980</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ted</td>
<td class="date">14/12/2010</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Jane</td>
<td class="date">08/08/2005</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to every one who helped me out with this one.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<table id="dates_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td class="date">01/02/2003</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Johnny</td>
        <td class="date">03/02/1980</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ted</td>
        <td class="date">14/12/2010</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td class="date">08/08/2005</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

CSS:

```
#dates_table tr {
    background: #00FF00;
}

#dates_table tr.past {
    background: #FF0000;
}​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#dates_table .date').each(function()
    {
        var row_date = Date.parse($(this).text().replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$2/$1/$3'));
        var now_date = new Date().getTime();
        if(row_date < now_date)
        {
            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('past');
        }
    }
    );
}
);​
```

Note I've added a `class="date"` to the date `<td>`s so position won't make a difference.

Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LPjfS/2/

Comment: thanks for that Chigley, but i think i have gone and right royaly confused my self. when i use the live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/LPjfS/2/ my table does what i want it to dao without any problems. but when i try to do it my self it is doing nothing. i duduced that i need to load jquery 1.4.2.js for my page which i have but know its doing nothing. this is the code i have come up with:

Comment: HTML:<html>
<head>
<style>
#sprog tr {
background: #00FF00;
}

#sprog tr.past {
background: #FF0000;
}
</style>
<script scr="jquery 1.4.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function()
{
$('#sprog .date').each(function()
{
var row_date = Date.parse($(this).text().replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$2/$1/$3'));
var now_date = new Date().getTime();
if(row_date < now_date)
{
$(this).parent('tr').addClass('past');
}
}
);
}
);
</script>
<title>cells</title>
</head>
<body>

Comment: <table id="sprog">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>14/08/2010</td>
<td>20/10/2015</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td class="date">14/10/2010</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td class="date">04/10/2010</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10/12/2010</td>
<td class="date">12/10/2010</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12/10/2010</td>
<td class="date">01/01/1900</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Jason - Post a link to where I can look at your code and I'll see if I can spot what's wrong with it :) EDIT: Just seen your comments above, first thing that springs out is `<script scr` should read `<script src`

Comment: sorry i dont know how to make it sit like yours

Comment: @Jason - that's because comments aren't really the best place for code! You could edit your OP or add a link as a comment. Would make it easier for answerers!

Comment: sorry i dont actually have it up anywhere yet, can i email it to you in a word doc?

Comment: @Jason - just edit your question to include your current code so I can take a look. Or post it on something like JSFiddle.

Comment: @chigley - Thanks for all you help with this problem, it works out i wasn't calling the Jquery correctly. now that i have worked that out it is working fine.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer once the problem is solved. Green tick mark to the left of each answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript should work:

```
var theTable = $('yourTable').tBodies[0];

for(x=0;x<theTable.rows.length;x++) {
  if(theTable.rows[x].cells[11]=='foo') {
    theTable.rows[x].cells[11].style.whatever= 'bar';
  }
}
```

Code is untested - sorry - but should be pretty good.

A good explanation: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domtables